# AWS Connect - Getting permission error on Wisdom:getContent

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-connect

I am implementing Connect Wisdom in my CCP UI. I am able to search for content and suggestions appear for documents I had previously uploaded but when i click on a suggestion it fails to load and upon checking the api call I see the error:

`{"errorCode":"AccessDeniedException","message":"User: arn:aws:sts::xxxxxxxxx:assumed-role/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonConnect_Of0Wxxxxxxba/_<connect-username> is not authorized to perform: wisdom:GetContent on resource: arn:aws:wisdom:us-east-1:xxxxxxxxx:content/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx"}`

It being an assumed role and set by AWS means I cannot change what is already there. I have enabled Wisdom in the agent Security Profile this account is using.

I am thinking it could be an issue with how I registered content. I didnt create a Salesforce or Service Now integration but rather registered a knowledge base and uploaded content via .txt files to the knowledge base. The fact that suggestions appear when i search indicates i've done something right, its just the retrieving full document that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

A WISDOM_KNOWLEDGE_BASE association is required to get the content.

```
aws connect create-integration-association \
  --instance-id aaaaaaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaa-aaaaaaaaaaaa \
  --integration-type WISDOM_KNOWLEDGE_BASE \
  --integration-arn arn:aws:wisdom:us-east-1:123456789012:knowledge-base/11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111
```